# Me.Requery doesnt work?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to update a form based on a selection from a combobox. Here is how the for is laid out. The form has a combobox that has a list of cities in it. I select a city in this dropdown and then click the submit button. After clicking submit, all of the listboxes below are to update with the address information of that city. I have a seperate listbox for each part of the address.

Now, I am able to get this to work properly if I do the following:

```
Me.Address1.Requery
Me.Address2.Requery
Me.City.Requery
```

However, I am looking for a way to do this without having to add in a `Me.field.Requery` everytime I add a new field. I have tried `Me.Requery`, but that isnt working for me.

Comment: In what way are all of the boxes updating? Calculated Fields? VBA? Another Query?

Comment: @Evan I have a query named "ResultQuery" that selects all of the data based on what the value of the dropdown is. From there, each listbox then selects its appropiate part of the address. For instance, the "Address1" box is set to `SELECT [ResultQuery].[Address1] FROM ResultQuery; `

Comment: sounds like you need recalc. Requery calls the forms record source and updates all controls that are tied to that source. Recalc reevaluates controls where the source is expressions

Comment: @Evan, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could try loop through the controls. This would allow for flexibility if you decide to add more list boxes

```
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
Select Case ctl.ControlType
Case Case acTextBox, acComboBox, acListBox, acOptionGroup, acCheckBox 'adjust to taste

clt.requery

Case Else

End Select
Next
```